# May someone explain to me the 'each' method here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.getJSON("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?v=1.0&q=codecademy&callback=?",
  function(response) {
    console.log(response.responseData);
    $.each(response.responseData.entries, function (i,newsItem) {
        $("#newsfeed").append("<li>"+newsItem.title+"</li>");
    });
  });
```

-Code taken from Codecademy

After looking at the code along my paper and pencil in hand, I've come to comprehend the following things:

- We get the JSON data from the sight mentioned using the `getJSON` function
- We log to the console the `responseData` object which exists in the response object we got from the site
- After that, for all the entries (which we get from `response.responseData.entries`), we call a function which appends to a `newsFeed` element, the title of each entry

However, I failed to understand (even after a lot of trial and error-- removing some pieces of code and observing changes) the role of passing two arguments (`i` and `newsItem`) to the function for `$.each`. What exactly do those arguments mean and from where do we get them? What is their value?

Edit: Sorry for putting up a bad question. I actually did go to the docs and I did look-up the [.each function](http://api.jquery.com/each/), however, after seeing the first example I came back as it clearly did not have two arguments being passed to the function.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: `i` is the current index, `newsItem` is the current object property.

Comment: I commend you for going through the code piece by piece and not just asking "how it works?". But when trying to understand code in its fullest you should look at the docs, for js that's [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: see, I went here: http://api.jquery.com/each/, saw the first example and was like "what!!!" as it specified no arguments there either...sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These arguments is what the callback function for the `$.each` method requires.

The first argument (`i`) is the current index that the function is iterating on. First element will have the value of 0 for `i`, the second will have `1`, etc... If you are iterating over an object, this value will be the current key of the item.

The second parameter is the actual element for the current iteration.

A simple example:

```
$.each( [ "a", "b", "c" ], function( index, elem ){
  console.log( index, elem );
});
```

This will yield the following output:

```
0, "a"
1, "b"
2, "c"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this jQuery `$.each` documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/. 1st param is index, 2nd is the element.